# H-balanced morphism in FP-notes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In [FP_notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f09S8.png) in order to prove that $\overline{M}_{0,n}(P^r,d,t)$ is a fine moduli space (proposition 3) the writers introduced $n$ line bundles $H_i$ and a $H$-balanced morphism $X \rightarrow \overline{M}_{0,m}$.
I want to know how we understand that we should consider $H$-balanced morphism?

Comment: It would be helpful to give the full name of the notes and provide a link, even if people who are able to answer your question will recognize this as Fulton-Pandharipande's notes on quantum cohomology. As to your question, at a glance I think the balancing condition comes about because it's equivalent to (iii) of Definition 3.2 being satisfied.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The $H$-balanced morphisms are simply morphisms that are transverse to the divisor $H$.  In this case, after ordering the preimage points of $H_i$ in the domain of the morphism, you get a genus $0$ curve with the $n$ original marked points, together with $r+1$ additional "clusterrs" of $d$ marked points.  This defines a natural transformation from $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,n}(\mathbb{P}^r,d,t)$ to $\overline{M}_{0,n+(r+1)d}$ that is a torsor for $\mathbb{G}_m^r$.  Thus, $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,n}(\mathbb{P}^r,d,t)$ is representable.